# Find files over certain size under my home directory

Tags: bash, find

I am trying to find all 100M+ files under my home directory. I've tried :

```
find -type f -size +100M | ls -lh
```

It does not seem to work though as i need it to be in human readable format

Comment: http://www.unixcl.com/2009/01/find-largest-files-in-linux.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`ls` doesn't read from standard input. You can do `ls file`, but not `echo file | ls` or `find | ls` or otherwise pipe to it.

Conveniently, `find` has a `-exec` flag that lets you call a program with found files as arguments:

```
find . -type f -size +100M -exec ls -lh {} +
```